# Hide blocking operation with coroutine

Tags: c++, boost, zeromq, coroutine

I have a service that receives data via UDP and I'd like to add a few zmq subscribers. I also want to use zmq sockets without blocking. And I don't want to create a separate thread for it.

I could use `zmq_socket::receive(msg, ZMQ_DONTWAIT)` but this leads to a busy loop and 100% CPU utilization. I tried `boost::coroutines` from 1.58, but with no success - I wasn't able to *hide* blocking receive (socket `RCVTIMEO` was set to -1).

I believe I'm missing something and just use the tools improperly.
So the question is what is the correct way to *hide* blocking receive?

Comment: I dont know, but the common thing to do is to poll for data.   I thought coroutines had to explicitly yield - if that's the case, then you can't make a blocking call in them if you want something else too run.  To "hide" a blocking call, you need an additional thread.

Comment: @xaxxon, create a common `zmq_poller` somewhere inside and just call the callbacks on received data?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/zeromq/azmq/blob/master/doc/examples/actor/main.cpp
. AZMQ has a Boost ASIO based function async_receive. I have a feeling it would support coros. If I get around to running it, I will share an SO answer surely! @user1056837

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which zeromq wrapper library you are using so here is an example based on the core libzmq lib.

Use [zmq_poll](http://api.zeromq.org/4-3:zmq-poll) that way you can define the timeout and still do a blocking read.

```
// define one socket (could define multiple), set event on ZMQ_POLLIN.
zmq_pollitem_t items[] = {{socket1, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0}};

while(1)
{
  // here you are polling the socket(s) defined in items with a timeout of 10ms
  int rc = zmq_poll(items, 1, 10);

  // Check which item (socket) had the event
  if(items[0].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN)
  {
    // There is data available on socket1
    // So call recv here on socket1

  } 

  // do other stuff here
}
```

Alternatively if you only want to be notified on callbacks you could use

- [zloop](http://czmq.zeromq.org/manual:zloop) from czmq
- [azmq](http://github.com/zeromq/azmq) zeromq for asio

Comment: Well you dont need the while(1) but you do need to call zml_poll every so often. The idea is you integrate it into your main thread.  There has to be some thread somewhere calling recv. The other option is to use an async framework (like boost asio) I am not sure but maybe czmq has something similar.

Comment: I'm already using asio. Again we come to a problem that I have to call this polling manually whether on a timer or somehow else. But I'm looking for a solution that informs me about incoming data, just like asio does.

Comment: have you tried the zeromq wrapper for asio?  https://github.com/zeromq/azmq

Comment: I'm looking at it, but I thought I could do it somehow else without additional dependency.

Comment: So libzmq is a low level communication library and provides no async/reactor type services. So you need to either add some dependency (another one is zloop http://czmq.zeromq.org/manual:zloop) etc. The other option is create dedicated thread to handle all your zeromq sockets (using zmq_poll) and from there fire off the async events.